# Where is the documentation to write an event handler for input text box?

Tags: reason, rescript

**Originally I wanted to know:**

How do I write a handler for this?

```
type state = string;
type action = | ChangeName(string)
let reducer = (_state, action) => switch action { | ChangeName(text) => text }
[@react.component]
let make = () => {
    let (state, dispatch) = React.usefReducer(reducer, "");
     /* What is the parameter type and how do I decode it? */
    let onChange = ??? => dispatch(ChangeText(????));  
    <input value=state onChange/>
}
```

Specifically, what is the parameter type for the punned `onChange` handler and how do I decode it?

Every reference I come across is for `JS`, which I'm having difficulty translating to `Re`.

**EDIT**
The answer I found by scraping github:

```
let onChange = event => dispatch(ChangeName(ReactEvent.Form.target(event)##value));
```

Say I'd like to use another JSX element, where's the documentation? OR, is their a supposition that people coming to this from elsewhere have knowledge apriori? (I'm mostly comfortable with 'c').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the types of all the DOM attributes from https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-react/blob/v0.10.1/src/ReactDOM.res

This file contains bindings to ReScript-React's subset of DOM attributes. It has:

```
onChange: ReactEvent.Form.t => unit
```

`ReactEvent.Form` module is declared at https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-react/blob/v0.10.1/src/ReactEvent.resi#L168

When looking for anything specific to ReScript-React, search that repo.

Looks like you have the correct code to handle the event now. Btw, you have in some places the variant constructor `ChangeName` and in others `ChangeText`, I assume the correct one is one of those. The compiler will of course catch this too :-)

Comment: It was a hurried example typed up on the fly: `ChangeName/Text` was meant to be the same variant. 
Thanks for the docs.